# How to set Caddyfile log format?

Tags: logging, syslog, caddy, caddyfile

I am using caddy 2 as my proxy. and I try to set my caddy log format.

```
localhost:80 {
    reverse_proxy example:80
    log {
        output net logstash:5140
        format single_field common_log
    }
}
```

on version 1 there are predefined format
https://caddyserver.com/v1/docs/log  (from old version)
**common_log** and **combined**

however this config below doesn't work. I assumed, it is deprecated, like it is stated in their documentation.

```
localhost:80 {
    reverse_proxy example:80
    log {
        output net logstash:5140
        format single_field combined_log
    }
}
```

But, I would like to keep using the old format for the log instead of the json format. 
then i tried multiple format, but it is not really documented in their website, also couldn't find in the community forum either.

then i tried multiple solutions. but, it is not working.

```
localhost:80 {
    reverse_proxy example:80
    log {
        output net logstash:5140
        format single_field "{remote} - {user} [{when}] \"{method} {uri} {proto}\" {status} {size} \"{>Referer}\" \"{>User-Agent}\""
    }
}
```

Can someone help me out? What I expected ist,
the format look like this.

```
"127.0.0.1 - - [10/Apr/2020:14:10:12 +0000] \"localhost\" \"GET / HTTP/1.1\" 200 236 \"-\" \"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0\""
```

And common_log giving me output

```
"10.0.0.2 - - [11/Apr/2020:08:50:01 +0000] \"GET / HTTP/1.1\" 200 236\n"
```

custom input

```
format single_field "{remote} - {user} [{when}] \"{method} {uri} {proto}\" {status} {size} \"{>Referer}\" \"{>User-Agent}\""

"45.143.220.111 - - [11/Apr/2020:09:00:20 +0000] \"127.0.0.1\" \"GET /vtigercrm/vtigerservice.php HTTP/1.1\" 444 0 \"-\" \"libwww-perl/6.43\""
"45.143.220.111 - - [11/Apr/2020:09:00:20 +0000] \"_\" \"\\x16\\x03\\x01\\x02\\x00\\x01\\x00\\x01\\xFC\\x03\\x03\\x97s\\xD21\\x91\\xF6\\x88;\\x05\\x9C\\xFEs\\x99\\xB4\\x06\\xB6\\xC07Jd.aLC\\x9AR\\xE6\\x07\\x09\\x98\\xD6\\x1F\\x00\\x00\\xAC\\xC00\\xC0,\\xC0(\\xC0$\\xC0\\x14\\xC0\" 400 157 \"-\" \"-\""
```

Answer (score 3):

As of 2020/06/20, you can't use custom log format from official distribution.
But, they have a module called [format-encoder](https://github.com/caddyserver/format-encoder) can do this.

So you just need to build `caddy` with [format-encoder](https://github.com/caddyserver/format-encoder).
Then change the log format to `formatted`, and append a `template` string.
The `template`'s content is reference from [caddy's structured log](https://caddyserver.com/docs/logging#structured-logs).

For example, with below config:

```
log {
  format formatted "{ts} {level} {request>headers>User-Agent}"
}
```

The log output will look like this:

```
1585597114.7687502 info ["curl/7.64.1"]
```

Answer (score 0):

the current (as of 8/2023) correct(?!) way to get apache common logs is to use:

https://github.com/caddyserver/transform-encoder

you'll first need to add transform-encoder either by recompiling caddy or for 2.4.4 and up you can just install the package:

`caddy add-package github.com/caddyserver/transform-encoder`

then, in each server directive in your Caddyfile"

```
www {
 <other config>
 log {
   output stdout  #your prefered output location
   format transform "{common_log}"
 }
}
```

you can also do this will the format fully spelled out:

common log format:

```
    log  {
       output stdout
       format transform `{request>remote_ip} - {request>user_id} [{ts}] "{request>method} {request>uri} {request>proto}" {status} {size}` {
            time_format "02/Jan/2006:15:04:05 -0700"
       }
    }
```

or combined format (there is no shorthand for this):

```
    log  {
       output stdout
       format transform `{request>remote_ip} - {request>user_id} [{ts}] "{request>method} {request>uri} {request>proto}" {status} {size} "{request>headers>Referer>[0]}" "{request>headers>User-Agent>[0]}" "host:{request>host}"` {
          time_format "02/Jan/2006:15:04:05 -0700"
       }
    }
```

in my testing it is *ALSO* possible to do this on a global level, but it breaks (formats it poorly) the other logging (not access logs) and I dont know how to fix it.

as best I can tell this has to be done per server directive. :(